# Why minus operator on uint64_t gives me wrong results?

Tags: c, uint64

in my super advanced code below I try subtract next values from a big num.
I can't understand why this gives me wrong results.
I am using cygwin gcc.
`$ gcc --version` gives me `gcc (GCC) 6.4.0`

```
    uint64_t val = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL; // 0xFF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ULL = 8 bytes
    printf("[ 0]  %ju\n",  val);
    printf("[ 1]  %ju\n",  val -= 1e19);
    printf("[ 2]  %ju\n",  val -= 8e18);
    printf("[ 3]  %ju\n",  val -= 4e17);
    printf("[ 4]  %ju\n",  val -= 4e16);
    printf("[ 5]  %ju\n",  val -= 6e15);
    printf("[ 6]  %ju\n",  val -= 7e14);
```

`gcc -Wall main.c -o main.exe && ./main.exe` gives me results as below:

```
[ 0]  18446744073709551615
[ 1]  8446744073709551616 <- here and below should be 5
[ 2]  446744073709551616
[ 3]  46744073709551616
[ 4]  6744073709551616
[ 5]  744073709551616
[ 6]  44073709551616
```

Did you notice last digit? Similar things happened for other numbers, but I don't know the reason...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Note that `1e19` is a `double` (floating-point) constant not an integral value.

Comment: `1e19` is floating point, the `-=` again doing a conversion. _Not_ having an error is the exception, as floating point is an approximation.

Comment: Yes, this was the reason... Why I didn't notice that earlier... Thank You a lot.